# Setting language for multiple elements in CSS

Tags: css, iso

What is the simplest way in CSS 3 of specifying a international language variation for the quotes `Q`, `BLOCKQOTE` and `CITE`. The CSS below works, but it seems rather verbose:

```
:lang(af) > q, :lang(af) > blockquote, :lang(af) > cite {quotes: '“' '”' '‘' '’';}
```

I was looking for a less verbose solution, perhaps something like this:

```
:lang(af) > (q, blockquote, cite) {quotes: '“' '”' '‘' '’';}
```

But I'm not sure if this kind of CSS declerations is legal and supported by all browsers.

Comment: You can use CSS Preprocessors like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). But in CSS, you should group them separately, like in your first statement...

Comment: There's an pseudo-class in Webkit/FF called [`:any()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any) which does the trick, but it may seem pointless in situations like this. There's no option to group this selector at this time. We have to wait for [`:matches()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#matches) in CSS selectors level 4.

Answer (score 0):

How about having different classes and switch them bases con the locale? Obviusly no CSS based locale would be used...